# nullable array of nullable values in nestjs code first graphql

Tags: graphql, nestjs, code-first

How can I get a field of type array that allows nullable values when using the code-first approach in nestjs graphql.

The [example](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/23-graphql-code-first) shows that

```
  @Field(type => [String])
  ingredients: string[];
```

generates `[String!]!` in the `schema.gql` file. How can I get just `[String]`? using `{nullable: true}` gives me `[String!]`

I was hoping to find some type of utility or parameter in the `@Field` decorator, but It seems it isn't

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set `@Field(() => [String], { nullable: 'itemsAndList' })` as [described in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#object-types)

When the field is an array, we must manually indicate the array type in the Field() decorator's type function, as shown below:

```
@Field(type => [Post])
posts: Post[];
```

> Hint
> Using array bracket notation ([ ]), we can indicate the depth of the array. For example, using [[Int]] would represent an integer matrix.

To declare that an array's items (not the array itself) are nullable, set the nullable property to 'items' as shown below:

```js
@Field(type => [Post], { nullable: 'items' })
posts: Post[];`
```

> If both the array and its items are nullable, set nullable to 'itemsAndList' instead.

Comment: Hehe, shame on me. It's clear in the docs. I guess I was a little too lazy. I hope the wording of the question helps other lazy people in the future :)

Comment: As a lazy person that found this helpful, thank you! 

Comment: @Jay do have any idea about nullable just `List`?
I want my list to be nullable but not its items.

Comment: @e.hadid probably it's better to return an empty array instead of `null`